# Find max number of fields in any document in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to get the count of a maximum number of fields and their names present within any document in a MongoDB's collection.
For eg., there is a collection named testCollection having 10 documents in it with the arbitrary number of first level fields or keys.

I need to know the fastest way detect the document or document(s) having the max number of fields and their names.

I have tried with a brute force find all method and traversing each document, but this is not the desired solution for a collection with huge number of rows.

Comment: What is your use case? The fastest approach would be to maintain an indexed field with a count of the number of fields in each document, but the onus would be on your application code to maintain the count as fields are added and removed. Without explicitly tracking the field counts you would otherwise have to resort to a collection scan, however this requirement seems unusual.

Answer (score 0):

A tiny library that might help you:

```
npm install objectdigger
```

and the example:

```
var objectdigger = require("objectdigger")


var item = {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": {
        "c1" : "c1",
        "c2" : "c2",
        "c3" : {
            "c3a" : "c3a",
            "c3b" : "c3b",
            "c3c" : [
                { "c3ca" : "c3ca" },
                { "c3cb" : "c3cb" },
                "zzz",
                { 3: "444"}
            ]
        }
    }

};


console.log(objectdigger.findDeepest(item));
```

as for the output:

```
{ maxKey: 'c.c3.c3c.c3ca', value: 'c3ca', depth: 3 }
```